# Is Django-SocialAuth compatible with Django1.5 custom user?

Tags: django, django-socialauth, django-1.5

I am not very experienced with Django-SocialAuth, but I wonder if it is not working because of the new Django 1.5 custom user, where you can login with email instead of username. Having the custom user implemented I just tried to implement the SocialAuth into my existing Django 1.5 project. Which fails to login with Twitter.

Is any SocialAuth professional here to kindly advice what I could be missing?

I have been looking at many tutorials but nothing seems to work:

**Setting.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login-error/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.User'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.User'

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = 'xx'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = 'xx'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (                           
                           'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
                           'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                           )

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",    
    "django.core.context_processors.request",    
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'pipeline',
    'south',
    'social_auth',
    'my_app',    
)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls'),name="twitter"),
(r'^login/$', custom_login),
```

**login.html**

```
<a href='{% url "socialauth_begin" "twitter" %}'>twitter</a>
```

**Error Message:**

```
URLError at /login/twitter/
<urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/twitter/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: URLError
Exception Value:    
<urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py in do_open, line 1181
```

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is the full traceback. It seems the token is not accepted (unauthorized_token). I have double checked the Twitter Key and secret key. Everything seems correct though.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/twitter/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
...
Traceback:
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/decorators.py" in wrapper
  29.             return func(request, request.social_auth_backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py" in auth
  31.     return auth_process(request, backend)
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py" in auth_process
  97.         return HttpResponseRedirect(backend.auth_url())
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py" in auth_url
  620.         token = self.unauthorized_token()
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py" in unauthorized_token
  679.         return Token.from_string(self.fetch_response(request))
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py" in fetch_response
  701.         response = dsa_urlopen(request.to_url())
File "/home/kave/vc/d-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/utils.py" in dsa_urlopen
  255.     return urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  127.     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  401.         response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _open
  419.                                   '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  379.             result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in https_open
  1219.             return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in do_open
  1181.             raise URLError(err)

Exception Type: URLError at /login/twitter/
Exception Value: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Comment: Yes, DSA is compatible with custom user model, there's no need to define `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL`, the app defaults to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` if defined. Why are you naming the `url(..., name="twitter")`? Regarding the error, you are getting a timeout, probably when the backend tries to get the request-token from Twitter API, could you share a more detailed traceback?

Comment: I have applied the couple of suggestions you had. Still no joy. I have edited the full traceback.  There is something about `unauthorized_token`. Please see update

Comment: IMO, the problem is with your server instance (or local machine), what happens when you do a "curl 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token' or in a python shell urllib2.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')? It should drop an error (401 not authorized or invalid-to-verify oauth error), but not a timeout.